# My CSS selector ":active" not working

Tags: css, css-selectors

```css
#selec:active{background-color:#000000;}
```

```html
<a href="<?php>phpscript-dynamic<?>"><div id="selec">TITLE</div></a>
```

But it doesn't work... I am using `<div><a></a></div>`, but does not work either.

Anyone can help me?

---

The code:

::CSS::

`#selec:hover{background-color:blue;}` *#working*

`#selec:active{background-color:red;}`**#not work**

::PHP::

```
<a href="?room=<?php echo $ID;?>"><div id="selec"><?php $name;?></div></a>
```

Thank you

Comment: @Engineer Interesting, it works in my Chrome too.

Comment: @JuanLie What browser are you using?

Comment: @bažmegakapa Here is an extended [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/zMtMn/1/) ...And it works fine.

Comment: @Engineer Seems like the [CSS2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes) is quite lenient in this matter. The behavior may be different in browsers?

Comment: @bažmegakapa `OUTTER DIV`(in my [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/zMtMn/1/)) does not work in IE9.It does not work without `onclick="return false"`(this stops the propagation) too.

Comment: @all: all web browser but same didn't work. In #selec :hover{} its work. but active or selected not work
note: its php script above not .php

Answer (score 4):

The [CSS3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#useraction-pseudos) states that:

> There may be document language or implementation specific limits on
>   which elements can become :active or acquire :focus.

So it does not state that it should not work on your div. Since the specification is lenient about this, there might be browser implementation differences. The [demo by @Engineer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483522/my-css-selector-active-not-working/11483537#comment15165186_11483522) showed me that your code works in Chrome.

Since the `a` element is sure to have an `:active` state in every browser, the following would certainly work for example:

```css
#selec a:active {background-color:#000000;}
```

```html
<div id="selec"><a href="dynamic.php">TITLE</a></div>
```

Here, you are using `:active` on the `a` that is a child of `#selec`. You make use of the [descendant selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/descendantselector).

It should also work the other way round - the `:active` selector is still on the `a`:

```css
a:active #selec {background-color:#000000;}
```

```html
<a href="dynamic.php"><div id="selec">TITLE</div></a>
```

Comment: "CSS does not define which elements may be in the above states"

Comment: @BoltClock The [CSS3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#useraction-pseudos) says basically the same - since the spec does not define it, the problem might be caused by browser differences?

Comment: That is most likely the case.

Comment: @BoltClock Revised my answer.

Comment: @all: all web browser but same didn't work. In #selec :hover{} its work. but active or selected not work
note: its php script above not .php

Comment: @JuanLie Could you create a jsFiddle demo that shows the problem? It might be something specific in your code.

Comment: @bažmegakapa : Thanks for your assistance . This the code:
`#selec:hover{background-color:#000;}
#selec:active{background-color:#000;}#not work`

`<a href="?room=<?php echo $ID;?>"><div id="selec"><?php $name;?></div></a>`
please, thanks

Comment: @JuanLie I already asked you to create a jsFiddle demo. Or any other kind of demo or page that SHOWS it not working. Without that, we cannot get any further with the details you have provided. Sorry.